# Symfony2 form : how to populate dynamically added entity field with a query result after creation?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In a Symfony 2.7 project,
let's say we have a form composed of 2 fields 'date'(date) and 'group'(entity), both have their own EventListener attached to, for `FormEvents::SUBMIT` events.

After the first submit, I'd like to add a new field 'travels' to the form and populate it with the result of a query using the two previous fields as criterias.

How to prevent 'travels' entity field from fetching all 'travel' in the DB and populate it manually after the raised events ?
I certainly miss some comprehension, I'm new to Symfony.

I know I can pass data directly in 'choices' option when creating 'travels' in each event but it would make useless DB calls.
I might count the number of registered events (of interest) and create 'travels' field when last event happens but it seems kind of weird...

Is there a clean solution for this case ?
(excuse for English, not my native language)

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Form;
// use directives...

class TravelRequestsWorklistType extends AbstractType {
private $em;
private $travelRepository;
private $searchQueryBuilder;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
  $this->em = $em;
  $this->travelRepository = $this->em->getRepository(Travel::class);
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
  $formFactory = $builder->getFormFactory();

  $builder
    ->add('requestedDate', 'date', array(
                                          'widget' => 'single_text',
                                          'input' => 'datetime',
                                          'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                                          'attr' => array('class' => 'date'),
                                          'data' => null,
                                          'mapped' => false
    ))
    ->add('selectedGroup', 'entity', array(
                                      'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Group',
                                      'placeholder' => '',
                                      'mapped' => false,
                                      'multiple' => false,
    ))
    ->add('search', 'submit');

    $builder->get('requestedDate')->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT,
                                                    $this->onDateCriteriaEvent($formFactory));
    $builder->get('selectedGroup')->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT,
                                                    $this->onGroupCriteriaEvent($formFactory));
}

private function onDateCriteriaEvent(FormFactory $ff) {
  return
  function(FormEvent $event) use ($ff) {
    $root = $event->getForm()->getParent();
    $requestedDate = $event->getData();

    $qb = $this->getQueryBuilder();
    $qb->andWhere('r.requestedDate = :requestedDate')
    ->setParameter('requestedDate', $requestedDate);

    if(!$this->searchHasResult($root)) {
      $this->addTravels($ff, $root);
    }
  };
}

private function onGroupCriteriaEvent(FormFactory $ff) {
  return
  function(FormEvent $event) use ($ff) {
    $root = $event->getForm()->getRoot();
    $selectedGroup = $event->getData();

    $qb = $this->getQueryBuilder();
    $qb->andWhere('r.group = :group')
    ->setParameter('group', $selectedGroup);

    if(!$this->searchHasResult($root)) {
      $this->addTravels($ff, $root);
    }
  };
}

private function addTravels(FormFactory $ff, Form $rootForm) {
  $travels = $ff->createNamedBuilder('travels', 'entity', null,
              array(
                  'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Travel',
                  'mapped' => false,
                  'multiple' => true,
                  'expanded' => true,
                  'auto_initialize' => false
              ));
  $submitButton = $ff->createNamedBuilder('validate', 'submit');

  $travels->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $this->onSearchResult());
  $form->add($travels->getForm())->add($submitButton->getForm());
}

// The method setData() shows "This form should not contain extra fields"
private function onSearchResult() {
  return
  function(FormEvent $e) {
    $data = $this->searchResultQueryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    $e->setData($data);
  };
}

private function getQueryBuilder() {
  if(null === $this->searchQueryBuilder) {
    $this->searchResultQueryBuilder = $this->travelRepository->createQueryBuilder('r');
// add dummy where clause here in order to call "andWhere" indistinctly later
    $this->searchResultQueryBuilder->where("1 = 1");
  }
  return $this->searchQueryBuilder;
}

private function searchHasResult(Form $form) {
  return $form->has('travels');
}
}
```

Comment: Trying to elaborate and clean my old questions, I realize that I no longer understand what I really was trying to achieve here...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a piece of solution.

On `$formField->addEventListener()` we can set a priority order as the third argument. So I can know which event will be triggered the last.

There must be another solution (like registering all the events I want to monitor in some member array and check if they have been executed in each callback). For the moment setting hardcoded events priority without checking callbacks execution is OK (for only 2 events).

The field is populated during creation and not after but anyway, it works :).

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
  $formFactory = $builder->getFormFactory();

  $builder
    ->add('requestedDate', 'date', array(
                                          'widget' => 'single_text',
                                          'input' => 'datetime',
                                          'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                                          'attr' => array('class' => 'date'),
                                          'data' => null,
                                          'mapped' => false
    ))
    ->add('selectedGroup', 'entity', array(
                                      'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Group',
                                      'placeholder' => '',
                                      'mapped' => false,
                                      'multiple' => false,
    ))
    ->add('search', 'submit');

    // Here we could use a register method which would contain listener informations
    $builder->get('requestedDate')
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT,
                               $this->onDateCriteriaEvent($formFactory),
                               0); //Will be triggered first
    $builder->get('selectedGroup')
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT,
                               $this->onGroupCriteriaEvent($formFactory),
                               1); //Will be triggered after 1st
}


private function onDateCriteriaEvent(FormFactory $ff) {
  return
  function(FormEvent $event) use ($ff) {
    $root = $event->getForm()->getParent();
    $qb = $this->getQueryBuilder();

    if(null !== $event->getData()) {
      $requestedDate = $event->getData();
      $qb->andWhere('r.requestedDate = :requestedDate')
         ->setParameter('requestedDate', $requestedDate);
      // Here we could check for registered events not already raised 
      // and do the appropriate action (if it is the last or something else...)
    }
  };
}

private function onGroupCriteriaEvent(FormFactory $ff) {
  return
  function(FormEvent $event) use ($ff) {
    $qb = $this->getQueryBuilder();
    $root = $event->getForm()->getRoot();

    if(null !== $event->getData()) {
      // Check for events not already raised....

      $selectedGroup = $event->getData();

      $qb->andWhere('r.group = :group')
         ->setParameter('group', $selectedGroup);
    }

    $travels = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    if($this->searchHasResult($root) {
        // We know this event is the last raised so we can add 'travels' field
        $this->addTravels($ff, $root);
    }
  };
}

private function addTravels(FormFactory $ff, Form $rootForm) {
  $travels = $ff->createNamedBuilder('travels', 'entity', null,
              array(
                  'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Travel',
                  'mapped' => false,
                  'multiple' => true,
                  'expanded' => true,
                  'auto_initialize' => false
              ));
  $submitButton = $ff->createNamedBuilder('validate', 'submit');

  $travels->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $this->onSearchResult());
  $form->add($travels->getForm())->add($submitButton->getForm());
}
```